# Why we assume a negative charge inside a cavity of non-conductors?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, insulators

The electric field of a spherical non-conductor, with uniform charge density $\rho$ is,
$$E_s(r)=\frac{\rho r}{3\epsilon_0}$$
It is mentioned in a lot of places that the electric field inside the cavity is,
$$E_c(r)=\frac{-\rho r}{3\epsilon_0}$$
This solution is often used to describe the electric field outside due to non-conductor with a cavity,
$$E_{total}(r)=E_s(R)-E_c(r)$$; where $R$ is the distance of the place where we want to find the electric field and $r$ is the radius of the cavity.

Now my question is, **why do we assume negative charge inside the cavity? Is it due to the ease of problem solving (using superposition principle) or there actually is a charge (induced due to the non-conductor)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual charge in the cavity. It is just to consider the cavity as superposition of positive and negative charges with the same volume charge density, so that you have superposition of two spheres with different sizes but the same volume charge density, and that the problem can be solved easily. Because the field due to a uniformly charged sphere is well-known.